# JS change elements css with :before

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am not a pro at css but I need somehow to access this styles:

```
.file__add:before {
      content: '';
      width: 56px;
      height: 56px;
}
```

I want to change this css snippet but I only know how to point to the main class (file__add):

```
$('.file__add').css('width', '200px')
```

How to point to that class with (:before) tag? Hope you got it, please help!

Comment: ::before is a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), not a dom element. So you can’t select it.

Comment: What is you suggestion then? How to make it come true?

Comment: What exactly you want to do with the pseudo-element? Set the width to 200px? If that's the case, take a look at [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/1169519).

Comment: Maybe something like this `document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.file__add:before', 'width: attr(data-width)'); $('.file__add').data("width", 200px)`;

Comment: Guys guys nevermind, the question is downgraded. This is not what I wanted to ask, sorry and huge thanks to all of you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.file__add').addClass("newClass");
```

```css
.newClass:before{
content:"";
width:5px;
height:5px:
}
```

add a new class to your element and then apply :before pseudo element to that class